# can't make an acl deny rule with multiple rights

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this in powershell:

```
icacls documents /deny users:w
```

So with this as a guide:  https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/ , I'm trying this.  The rights are actually both write and synchronize (surprise), 'Write, Synchronize'.

```
$acl = Get-Acl documents
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
  'Users','Write, Synchronize','Deny')
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl documents
```

But $accessrule only has "Write" inside it:

```
$accessrule

FileSystemRights  : Write
AccessControlType : Deny
IdentityReference : Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

And if I cast the rights with the right type it works:

```
[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]'write,synchronize'
Write, Synchronize
```

Even if I use the equivalent number for the rights enum, 1048854, only the 'Write' property shows up.

Or if I copy the rights from another file, it works fine.

```
get-acl file1 | set-acl documents
```

Comment: It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights) that _"This value (Synchronize) is automatically set when allowing access and automatically excluded when denying access."_. Since you are setting a rule that denies access, the synchronize bit no. 20 is automatically removed.

Comment: @Theo You're right.  With 'Allow', I can use both rights.  I guess icacls didn't get that memo.  The gui works the same way.  Related:  https://superuser.com/a/1544319/332578